# Как осуществляется поиск и создание требуемого контроллера

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Хотелось бы поподробнее узнать каким образом в asp.net core осуществляется сопоставление строкового имени контроллера с соответствующим классом, и как потомпроисходит его создание и вызов. Однако, не удается найти место где это происходит. Буду благодарен за описание этого процесса или хотя бы на указание в каких классах искать соответствующий код.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под строковым именем контроллера? И кто должен создавать и вызывать контроллер? Давайте на примере: что нужно сделать?

Comment: Хочу понять каким наиболее разумным способом можно вызвать метод Add() класса Product при получении от пользователя строки "Product/Add". Подумал, что наиболее наглядную реализацию этого можно подсмотреть в asp.net.

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов создание именно контроллера происходит через IControllerFactory/IControllerActivator - [посмотрите реализацию в исходниках фреймворка](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Controllers/DefaultControllerFactory.cs).

Comment: @КонстантинГалиахметов то есть, вы хотите понять, как правильно обработать пришедший с клиента запрос `[имя сервера]/product/add`?

Comment: @eastwing Я хочу понять как осуществляется создание класса Product по его имени. То есть от пользователя приходит имя класса в виде строки и я хочу сопоставить это имя с существующим классом и вызвать его. Хочу увидеть как это работает в asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю на вопрос так, как его понял я :)

Запросы, приходящие с клиента маршрутизируются. А маршрутизацией управляете вы как программист. Т.е. это вы указываете серверному приложению, какая часть URI чему соответствует. В [MVC обычно используются специальные middleware](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing); само сопоставление в вашем случае будет примерно таким:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // ...

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("add", "add", new { controller = "Product", action = "Add" });
        // ...
    });

    // ...
}
```

Здесь предполагается, что у вас есть контроллер, содержащий метод `Add`:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // ...
    public IActionResult Add ()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, контроллер должен называться именно так: `ProductController`, и располагаться он должен в папке `Controllers` вашего проекта.

Есть другой подход, он чаще используется в приложениях WebAPI. Продемонстрирую на примере:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // ...
    [Route("add")]
    public IActionResult Add ()
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

То есть, вы явно указываете приложению, как реагировать на URI. Строка `[Route("[controller]")]` указывает на имя контроллера - в данном случае это `Product`. Метод Add относится к классу контроллера, поэтому атрибут `[Route("add")]` соответствует URI `[адрес сервера]/product/add`. Правилаименования и расположения остаются теми же.

Надо отметить, что любой подход можно использовать в любом типе приложений; с технической точки зрения "проект приложения MVC" и "проект приложения WebAPI" - это просто наборы предустановок.

---

Это крайне упрощённый ответ, который прямо отвечает на вопрос (как его понял я) - и не более того. В примерах опущено много необходимого для корректной работы приложения ASP.NET кода. Разумеется, необходимо изучать матчасть, начиная с [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/).